# How do I make a smooth transition when moving an element from margin-left:-9999px to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's some more details - due to some weird restrictions with the YouTube API, I am forced to push a container off the page to give the impression of hiding the container.

I achieve this by using this class:

```
.my_hide{
    margin-left:-9999px;
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

And by using the JQuery methods `$("player-list_container").removeClass("my_hide")` and `$("player-list_container").addClass("my_hide")` to control the toggling.

However, the toggling looks jaunty, and the container jumps up once the class is removed. I want to be able to transition smoothly from one state to the other, and am at a loss for how to do it.

This behaviour [can be demonstrated here](http://mixtape.meteor.com)

Add a video by typing in and searching for anything, and then hit the Play button located below. You should observe the behaviour described.

Comment: u can use the jquery anitmate() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iam assuming you 'are not able to'/'not want to' manually hide the container but want to change its position so that it is outside the boundaries of the page and it looks hidden.

In that case changing the position property will definitely give you a jumpy instead of a smooth effect since this affects the whole layout of the page ([Read more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)).  What you can instead do is change its position using CSS3 animation's **translate** property.

Here's a demo I've coded which does exactly what you want. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgcIi

The "Click me" button toggles between taking the container off and on the page and it does it smoothly. You can also adjust the time which it takes to change the position of container. (As of now its 500ms)

Answer (score 2):

> I want it to look like the container is fading in in position meaning I would have to get the container to that position before using any type of animation function.

Then, don't throw the element way off the page with CSS. Leave it where it is, and hide it with `.hide()`. Then fade it in with `.fadeIn()`.

You'll need to manually size the container, as it won't expand to contain a hidden element.

Comment: I mentioned in the beginning of my post that that is not an option due to the limitations of the YouTube API. I've researched this problem well, and moving the container off the page would be the best fix, I just need to figure out how to work around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On my screen it just popped up. Im not 100% sure what type of pop in effect you want but that said, check out http://api.jquery.com/animate/

i was going to code up an example but that page has a bunch!

good luck!

PS: scroll down for all the visual animation examples.
Here is some sample code:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
$( '.ytv' ).fadeTo( "fast", Math.random() );
    //add animation code here;
});
```

check out a ***rough*** fiddle.
edit: heres a rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/Lef9n/2/

just click the red area to the right of the video

Comment: Well the "pop up" of that container is not a desired effect. That's just the container taking the place it should be in. I want it to look like the container is fading in in position meaning I would have to get the container to that position before using any type of animation function.

Comment: I understand. Though the response will still be the same i suppose. For example, the div that dynamically holds the code that brings up the searched for content will be hidden but in place. Then once the play button is presssed, you can have it call a function and inside that fucntion, you can specify what effects it would have. for example, in that link they have animation for x/y axis so youd implement that on click and at the same time, it would animate the opacity etc. All youd need is in that link. Once you have both animations tested, wrap em in a function and on click have it play

Comment: I still have my doubts since I did try a solution like that using just `fadeTo` and `delays`, but I will read your link and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Animate function in jQuery wll help you

Comment: A little more detail might be helpful to the OP.